# How to change a combobox value in a programmatic way like it's was changed by the user (fire all events like mousedown, mouseup, onchange, etc)?

Tags: delphi

How to change a combobox value in a programmatic way like it's was changed by the user (fire all events like onmousedown, onmouseup, onkeydown, onkeyup, onchange, etc.)? Purpose is to make an automate for testing. same question for an Tedit

Answer (score 1):

Mimic the actual keyboard behavior using API's like [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) or its predecessors [`keybd_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) and [`mouse_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event). They can synthesize device input from keyboards and mice.

But even then it's tricky to get it right. Unless you want to spend numerous hours to get something that's remotely usable, I think it's better to use some macro tool (often free or cheap), or an actual testing tool (often a bit more expensive, but worth it). See [What scripting tool can I use for automated testing of Delphi programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863869/what-scripting-tool-can-i-use-for-automated-testing-of-delphi-programs) for some inspiration.